# Connecting to an NTP server keeps failing (Java)

Tags: java, networking, ntp

I'm just learning how to do networking in Java and the first simple example of getting the time from an NTP server keeps throwing a ConnectException. I'll copy and paste the code, but I have the feeling it must be something not code related since this code came out of a book.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class AskTime {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        if(a.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("your lame");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String machine = a[0];
        final int daytimeport = 13;
        Socket so = new Socket(machine,daytimeport);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream() ) );
        String time = br.readLine();
        System.out.printf("%s says it is %s %n", machine, time);
    }
}
```

The command I'm using to execute this is:

`java AskTime us.pool.ntp.org`

**Update:** After reading msaeed's advice I changed the port to 123 and am now being told connection refused instead of connection timed out. So I think msaeed is right, does anyone have any idea what else I need to communicate to receive a time?

Comment: Oh yeah and the "your lame" part was not from the code in the book everything else I'm fairly sure is identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently this code uses the old [`DAYTIME` protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAYTIME) that uses port 13.  [`NTP` protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) uses port 123 and requires a bit more communication.  Many of the `NTP` servers stopped supporting `DAYTIME` queries.

The NTP Project provides a sample code for an `NTP` client in Java [here](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient).

Comment: Any idea what else it requires to request a time?

Answer (score 1):

*msaeed* is right. You can use your code with DAYTIME server like 'time.nist.gov' - or pick any other from [this list](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi)

**Update** If your end goal is to communicate with NTP server (as opposed to play with sockets as you've said initially) you should look at [Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/). In fact, you should look at its source either way - Commons Net implements quite a few network protocols.